# How to change MS SQL db to MySQL without causing problems with EF and logic in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a web application with ASP.NET MVC 4, Entity Framework Code First - localDB MS SQL database. After contacting the hosting company, they told me their servers only support ASP.NET MVC apps with MySQL databases.

Now I need to find how to change the MS SQL db to MySQL db without causing serious problems with EF etc. I googled but didn't find good explanations on this subject.

I had some issues with Membership - authentication [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858274/asp-net-mvc-mysql-membership-provider-user-cannot-login).

And the steps explained [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider) didn't work for me.

Comment: You can use some tools and migrate MSSQL to MySQL

Comment: I have to implement it in my logic, I'm sure. I'll update my question with the issues I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [SSMA for MySQL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42657) to transfer data to MySQL first, then in code/web.config set the database type to MySQL ([first answer in this SO post explains how it is done for your ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602114/mysql-connector-6-8-2-rc-entity-framework-6-and-code-first)), then set new connection string and mysql providers in web.config and add references to MySQL connector binaries to the project.

When I did this I had some problems with tinyint(1) fields and DateType fields but that might be fixed in new connector versions.

I suggest you do not use mysql.web.dll for memberships but write your own membership/profile provider (about 300 LoC for my project) unless you need it as I had many problems with it in the past.

I also had some problems with session state provider because the inProc mode on shared hosting often causes sessions to time-out prematurely(Causing visitors to lose shopping carts/logout in certain scenarios) and the hosting provider did not have the session service running at the time so I had to use

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" cookieless="false" timeout="4000" customProvider="MySqlSessionStateProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="MySqlSessionStateProvider" type="MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="\app" description="app" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" />
        </providers>
 </sessionState>
```

and create the database tables first.

Considering the trouble and cost involved I would reconsider choosing a different web hosting.

Comment: Not really. Most of our websites are regional (Slovenia), international sites are on jodohost which is cheap but not very fast. They do support mssql and .net but you might want to watch out for intruders as their shared hosting is very liberal in allowed scripts. If you want to research more I suggest http://www.webhostingtalk.com/